# Adding a Hat list just like Badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash-2014

I like to collect **Badges** and other achievements, just like many other Stackoverflow users. Yesterday I was rewarded bye 2 new **Hats** and decided to collect them all. So I went looking for a list of available Hat, but didn't found any. Now my request is to make a list like that, with the description of awarding the **Hat**.

---

Of course I didn't forgot about the secret Hats. Their description shouldn't be next to the image, but it would be nice to also see their list.

---

Why I request this?

It's like I already wrote, I like to collect any achievement and then I have a clear survey over all he Hats. And I also belief may other users would like this.

Comment: http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/ The site is linked from the hat dialog and the Winter Bash snowflake icon drop-down.

Answer (score 2):

Its already http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/.

Make sure you are logged in there.